# Difficulty compiling with aobs-tikz with MikTeX on Windows, but not texlive on Linux

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I've made a presentation using Beamer. I use the aobs-tikz package for the overlay-beamer-styles. I can compile my presentation in Linux with texlive, but I can't compile it with MiKTeX on Windows.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}
    abc
\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

! Package tikz Error: I did not find the tikz library 'overlay-beamer-styles'.I looked for files named tikzlibraryoverlay-beamer-styles.code.tex and pgflibraryoverlay-beamer-styles.code.tex, but neither could be found in the current texmf trees..See the tikz package documentation for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... ...eamer-styles, arrows.meta, calc, external}

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you make sure to install the package `aobs-tikz` package in MikTeX? Are you sure it is up to date?

Comment: Please provide a MWE, so that others dont have to guess different packages....

Comment: I have the same problem (and added a MWE). If I add `tikzlibraryoverlay-beamer-styles.code.tex` mnually to the MWE folder it compiles. I am sure that `aobs-tikz` is installed in the most recent version.

Comment: It seems that MikTeX only extracts aobs-tikz.pdf while .ins file is not processed, so `tikzlibraryoverlay-beamer-styles.code.tex` is not automatically installed. I've filled a ticket about this problem.

Comment: try the solution proposed here  (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by a bug in MiKTeX (https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2442/).

Comment: @JosephWright That's an interesting take on this question. Isn't MikTeX a "related system" to TeX? If not, where is the line, and how is a future OP with a similar problem to know whether their question about a tikz error will be on-topic or not? Wouldn't this question be much better served by an answer stating "this was caused by a bug in MikTeX which has since been fixed; if you still observe this the fix is updating your distribution"?

Comment: @E.P. There's a long-standing convention on the site that bugs in TeX software may be off-topic. If the bug is in a 'current' TeX package and a fix can be posted, this is fine as an answer. However, if it's a fixed bug in a package then 'update your system' is the 'answer', but that would be no-value so is OT. For binaries, we can't really give a good answer so again usually OT, in particular when fixed in a release.

Comment: @E.P. Historically, we used to call these 'too localized' but the network got rid of that close reason. (There's a general feeling that lots of answers which are one liners and really don't help other users aren't that desirable.)

Comment: @JosephWright In that case, your comment above still strikes me as wrong. If indeed there is such a consensus, then surely there is some post on meta expressing this? (and, if not, it's high time there was one.) You would then close with a comment along the lines of "I am closing this question because it was caused by a *solved* bug in miktex; for more details see (this question on meta)". The current handling is not helpful to the OP (i.e. won't be in similar cases where OP is still active) and it actively discourages participation in this site.

Comment: @E.P. Being solved in MiKTeX isn't the point: we can't fix MiKTeX, only Christian Schenk can, so it would be OT ('report to CS') in any case. Closing is never meant to mean 'don't ask': we encourage solving issues in comment streams even where there's not a formal answer in a StackExchange sense.

Comment: @E.P. See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3492/why-are-questions-on-package-bugs-issues-too-localized and http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2622/questions-which-are-bug-reports?noredirect=1&lq=1, for example, on this. I'd be happy to see a meta question from you on this if you feel it needs wider discussion (won't show up to most people here)

Comment: @JosephWright ... you do realize you've linked to a consensus answer that repeats my points pretty much verbatim, right? You also don't seem to see the 'broken windows' aspect to closing on-topic questions: it doesn't mean "don't ask" to you, but it *does* mean precisely that to a newcomer who is wondering whether they can ask or they'll be shut down if they do, and this is yet another way in which this site is unfriendly to newcomers. It would be dead simple to link to meta/q/3492 in the closure reason, and actually provide some transparency to the moderation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49543/discussion-between-joseph-wright-and-e-p).

Comment: @E.P. Why don't you stop responding and read what has been said instead? If the question cannot be answered within TeX code there is nothing we can do. unfriendly you say...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was caused by a bug in MiKTeX (sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2442) and now it is **fixed**

Comment: @percusse Thanks for that random bit of unwarranted aggression. I'm sure it made you feel really well about yourself.

Comment: @E.P. Or you simply take everything in a hostile manner. Where is the aggression? Calling unfriendly and opaque moderation because we closed a question after a year after it is fixed already ? Let's stop here then